# Gitlab CI: How to run tests in pipeline using docker and shell runner

Tags: node.js, meteor, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I need to run tests in my gitlab CI pipeline. This is how my YAML document looks like:

```
before_script:
  - docker info

build:
  script:
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION
```

I'm using a shell runner. And now I want to check for correct eslint, which would look like:

```
eslint .
```

In a second step I want to do some unit testing using mocha

```
meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha
```

How can I do this in the pipeline using the already build container/image? How should I implement this into the YAML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to run `eslint` in your newly built container. You could do it by adding the following to your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
lint:
  script:
    # This step is probably optional
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION
    # This will run eslint inside the container
    - docker run -it $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION eslint .
```

If there are any linting errors, the exit code should be non-zero which will make the job fail (which is probably what you want).

Comment: This gives me the error `the input device is not a TTY`. What does that mean? If I remove the `-t`, I get the error `starting container process caused "exec: \"eslint\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

Comment: How is eslint installed in the container? You may have to specify the full path to  eslint or add eslint to your $PATH (for instance in the Dockerfile before building the container)

Comment: eslint is a devDependency. You are right: In the productive build there are no devDependencies. So how should I do my tests for that productive build? Or do I have to build a second container for all tests?

Comment: Is there a reason why you run the tests in a container and not straight from the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: Hmm. No. As you see this is very new for me, so I am not very experienced. The application is a meteor app, so I thought I have to do a build first. With this build I tried to do the tests and if they are successful, I would deploy it...

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to take the build, put it into a new docker image with DB and what is needed and run the tests in this new testing container?